# How to multiply (broadcast) between pd dataframe?

Tags: python

```
df1:
     A     B     C     D
0    1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1    5.0   10.0  15.0  20.0
2    10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0
```

I got df2 by:

```
df2 = 10 / df1.iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
df2:
A  10.0
B  5.0
C  3.3
D  2.5
```

I want to multiply df2 to entire df1 and the output I expect is:

```
     A      B     C      D
0    10.0   10.0   10.0  10.0
1    50.0   50.0   50.0  50.0
2    100.0  100.0  100.0 100.0
```

I tried below:

```
df1 * df2
```

I thought that it should work, but it did not.

Can you help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Use `df = df1.mul(df2)`

Comment: It is dupe :( Unfortunately.

Comment: Or `df *= 10/df.iloc[0]` works for me

Comment: And all together `df = df1.div(df1.iloc[0]).mul(10)`

Comment: Hmm...I tried all you answered. But I got this message:"ValueError : operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,) (4,)." ...